# Get current name for path in url

Tags: php, url

How can i grab everything that is after `http://www.domain.com/somefolder/` in php.For e.g  if `http://www.domain.com/somefolder/login` is accessed ,  i just need the `login` part.

I tried the following

`basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);` and `basename(__FILE__);` both gives me index.php

Comment: You would use some URL parsing or string manipulation (regex for example). Have you attempted to solve this yourself? Can you please share some attempts (with code) that you have made?

Comment: What you are looking for is called "Friendly URL in PHP" it's achieved by a mix of .htaccess rules and php

Comment: are you using any framework?

Comment: @Lix code have been added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` was what i need

P.S Ty for the downvotes

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `strlen` and `substr` functions:

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://www.domain.com/somefolder/login';
    $remove = 'http://www.domain.com/somefolder/';
    echo substr($url, strlen($remove));
```

**EDIT** And you should make sure that your urls always start with www. subdomain. Otherwise you can get unexpected results.